# Android, how to observe LiveData from within the same ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm a complete novice when it comes to LiveData and MVVM architecture. I'm trying to figure out how to observe a LiveData<List> in the ViewModel to update another variable depending on if it is empty or not.

I'm getting the LiveData from my Room database with this:

```
class MealsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mealDao : MealDao
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    private val currentDay: MutableLiveData<Date> = MutableLiveData(Date())
    val meals = Transformations.switchMap(currentDay){ date -> mealDao.getMeals(date).asLiveData() }
```

I would like for another variable in the ViewModel, `private val empty: Boolean`, to update anytime the list is returned empty (null). This will be used in updating an ImageView in the Fragment from Visible.GONE to Visible.VISIBLE.

How do I check if `val meals` is empty synchronously?

I've read around and saw some people said to use`observeForever`, but the architecture guide explicitly advises against any observers in ViewModels.

I could probably observe the LiveData in the Fragment, but that would require business logic in the Fragment, ie:

```
viewModel.meals.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

    if meals.value.isEmpty() imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE else imageView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

And I'd like to keep the Fragment as 'dumb' as possible, so I'd prefer to have that logic in the ViewModel. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check live data `meal` to see if it's empty or null and then trigger with your live data `empty` like this:

In the viewmodel, you create a livedata `isEmptyMeals`. This live data variable will always trigger when `meals` value change and will check if your `meals` value are empty or null.

*MealsViewModel.kt*

```
class MealsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mealDao : MealDao
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    private val currentDay: MutableLiveData<Date> = MutableLiveData(Date())
    val meals = Transformations.switchMap(currentDay){ date -> mealDao.getMeals(date).asLiveData() }
    
    val isEmptyMeals = meals.map {
        it.isNullOrEmpty()
    }
}
```

And in the fragment, you will listen to observe the livedata `isEmptyMeals` and perform the logic to hide or show the image view you want.

*Fragment.kt*

```
viewModel.isEmptyMeals.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    imageView.visibility = if (it) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Comment: I moved `if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE` into the .map within the ViewModel, and it worked perfectly. The Fragment was nice and simple afterward with imageView.visibility = it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your code is set up but you can do something like below

Add variable to ViewModel

```
val empty = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

In `meals` observer
viewModel.meals.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

```
viewModel.empty,postValue(meals.value.isEmpty())
```

Then observe from `empty`

Using MediatorLiveData

In your ViewModel class, create

```
val empty = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
```

Then

```
empty.addSource(meals) {
    empty.value = it.isEmpty()
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So you're suggesting that I should observe the LiveData and update val empty in the ViewModel from the fragment? Would that violate the principles of MVVM at all?

Comment: In your case, it is easier to do so. You can also use ```MediatorLiveData``` if you understand the basics correctly.  MediatorLiveData is the suggested option.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData

Comment: I also updated the answer with ```MediatorLiveData```

Comment: Using `MediatorLiveData` is also one way. But it is often used when there are **multiple livedata sources** that you need to listen to. Because here he wants to check if livedata `meals` is null or empty. So we will use the Transformation LiveData extension `map`. The extension `map` is essentially generated from `MediatorLiveData`. In general, use MediatorLiveData in case you need to listen to many livedata sources, but if you only listen to 1 livedata source change, you should use the Transformation `map` extension.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that skipped my mind. But that will be the same as my first implementation.